# How can I prove that $\mathbb{S}_{+}^n$ is a closed and convex set?

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, symmetric-matrices, convex-geometry

$\mathbb{S}_{+}^n$ is the set of positive semidefinite (and symmetric) real matrices of size $n\times n$. I have to prove that this set is a closed convex cone. How can I do?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of closed, convex, and cone? Can you show any of the three properties?

Comment: It is not closed. ${ 1 \over n} I \to 0$. The other properties are just a matter of grinding through the definitions.

Comment: I expect positive means positive definite as in $Ax\cdot x\geq0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft that would be positive *semi*definite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A \ge 0$ **iff** $x^TAx \ge 0$ for all $x$ **iff** $A \in \cap_x \{ B | x^T B x 
 \ge 0\}$.

Note that for any $x$ that $\{ B | x^T B x   \ge 0\}$ is a closed half space (hence convex). Since $0 \in \{ B | x^T B x   \ge 0\}$ we see that it is a cone as well.